# beeline and hive queries in metastore tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have cloudera quickstart 5.5 on linux red hat.
I try create metastore tables by hue, but these tables were created in hive1 instead of hive2 too. 
So when I do queries by hive line, queries and show tables works, but in beeline (hive2) is empty (show tables no dispaly anitihng).
How I create tables by hue or other way to be able to consult  queries by beeline?
Thanks.

Comment: what is the backend database for your Metastore?

Comment: Metastore tables are in default database

Comment: My question was if you have configured another dabase to store Hive metadata. By default it is Derby local database, but you could use MySQL, Postrgres, Oracle o MS Server to hold those data. So are you using any f those? or you are using the default Derby local database?

Comment: would you put the hive-site.xml configuration if it is possible? Not the whole file, just the properties defining the dataabse connection and location

Comment: I believe that is because hive1 uses metastore folder other than this used by hive2. and here you could not see the tables created by hive1 in hive2

Comment: I´m using default Derby local database, now shows databse and tables 0: jdbc:hive2://> show databases;
14/01/31 16:50:47 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=compile from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
...
+----------------+
| database_name  |
+----------------+
| default     |
+----------------+
 
1 row selected (0.026 seconds)


but when i do this: 
0: jdbc:hive2://> Select * from GOLD
0: jdbc:hive2://> 'Select * from gold'
or
0: jdbc:hive2://>Select * from gold;
0: jdbc:hive2://>Select * from gold > /path/
 I don´t see the result anywhere